# How to manage time in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

**Auction servlet**- This is a java servlet that waits for 2-3 minutes after the first user made the request.so i need to keep track of time in my servlet.
so when the time finishes using some logic it would send response to some users...

**Example:** 
lets say my 10 users are sending a request to my auction servlet, and I want to check that, 2-3 minutes have been passed since that first user made request

and when the time finishes,  using some logic i want to send a response to my some users after 2-3 minutes.

I have tried to use TimerTask in HTTpServelt but got an error of access denied.

Comment: question hard to understand, give some details, what You have done?

Comment: @BalusC I doubt it is a duplicate, TimerTaks is not for measuring but for scheduling. Although I agree it is hard to tell what the actual question is.

Comment: sorry for not making it more clear.. Basically I would like to run my servlet for 2-3 minutes and then stop  but i do not want to use  a cron jobs here

Comment: @vickydhudasiya Edit your Question with clarifications rather than posting as Comments.

Comment: @Basil Bourque I have edited the question.. please let me know what do you think about it

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear. You may not fully understand how [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) technology works.

A Servlet is a class that is loaded upon first request by a client (web browser, etc.) or preloaded when [servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) starts. A thread is assigned to handle each incoming request to generate the outgoing response. Normally the **servlet object does not stop running** once started, until the servlet container closes. You must understand that a single servlet object servlets handles many request-response cycles by many users. See more [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/642706).

A session is launched for each individual user’s set of request-response cycles. Each session is represented by a [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) object. Sessions automatically time-out if the user stops making requests. Implementations commonly default to a half-hour until time-out. You can adjust that default. This is probably the solution you are looking for, but I'm not sure given the lack of clarity in your question. Call [`setMaxInactiveInterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval-int-) on that session object.

```
int seconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 3 ) ;  // Three minutes converted to a number of seconds.
someHttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval( seconds );
```

Also, you can programmatically close a session by calling [`invalidate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate--) on that session object, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5334913/642706).

You can ask for that session’s start time as a count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970 UTC by calling [`getCreationTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getCreationTime--).

```
long millisSinceEpoch = someHttpSession.getCreationTime();
```

Make an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from that to see that moment in UTC.

```
Instant instantSessionStarted = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch );
```

Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object to see elapsed time. For current moment, call `Instant.now`.

```
Duration durationOfThisSession = Duration.between( instantSessionStarted , Instant.now() );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.. This answer really help me to understand some servlet concepts